# cross referencing to doxygenfunction from sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, doxygen, restructuredtext, cross-reference

I have a problem with C++ domain. In my index.rst I have

```
:cpp:func:`Hello()`
```

In hallo.rst I have the following lines:

```
.. cpp:function:: Hello

.. doxygenfunction:: Hello
```

The line with doxygenfunction works and I get the documentation generated for my function.

But the line with cpp:function doesn't work. Instead, I'm trying to generate a link for the Hello() function in the documentation.

I generated my C++ documentation with Sphinx, Doxygen and Breathe.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got your Question right. In the documentation of Breathe it is listed how to link a function.

**doxygenfunction**

This directive generates the appropriate output for a single function. The function name is required to be unique in the project.

```
.. doxygenfunction:: <function name>
   :project: ...
   :path: ...
   :outline:
   :no-link:
```

Check out: https://breathe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/directives.html#doxygenfunction

There is also an example page on how to link a single function: https://breathe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/function.html#function-example